# How do i work with HttpWebRequest object in Windows Application programs?

Tags: .net, winforms

I want to write an application that sends HTTP Requests to the server.
I want use .net framework for this.

I want to create a request like this:

```
    POST http://example.com/Mypage.aspx HTTP/1.1
    Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
    Accept-Language: en-US
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate
    Connection: Keep -Alive
    Content-Length: 482
    DNT: 1
    Host: example.Com
    Pragma: no-Cache

    page=en_UserPage&ProceedStep1=1&username=%textbox1.value%&password=%textbox2.value%&password2=%textbox3.value%&name=%textbox4.value%
```

now i have two problems, first is how do i make the last two lines: an empty line and a line that i can write those values?

Second how do i have to encode values. for example the "name" property gets values like: "first_name=%DA%A9%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%85%D9%87".

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
    using System.Net;

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/Mypage.aspx");

    var postData = "en_UserPage&ProceedStep1=1&username="+ textbox1.value +"&password=" + textbox2.value +"&password2=" + textbox3.value+"name=" + textbox4.value;

   var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

   request.Method = "POST";
   request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   request.ContentLength = 482;
   request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
   request.Accept = "gzip, deflate";

   using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
   {
    stream.Write(data, 0, 482);
   }

   var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

   var responseString = new    StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

For more on visit [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)